# Players Matching Algorithm

Tags: c++

Example when player register tournament push `vector` and when start game matching players and add the `list` (`list` have struct and 2 players insert 1 `list`) and erase in `vector`.
Winner player add repeat `vector`. When round is finish (example `vector` have 101 players, matching 100 players fight and winner is insert again attenders `vector` 101th player is pass by and move next round). I'm i'm struggling for matching, i'm coding but when move next round enters an infinite loop. What is my mistakes? (sorry for bad English)
My codes;

```
struct sFighters
{
    sFighters(int p1, int p2) : p1(p1), p2(p2) {}
    int p1;
    int p2;
};

std::vector<int> vec;
std::list<sFighters> dList;

void AddVec(int id)
{
    if (const auto& it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), id); it == vec.end())
        vec.push_back(id)
    else
        std::cout << "Already in vec" << std::endl;
}

void MakeList()
{
    for (auto i = vec.size() - 1; i > 0; i-=2 )
    {
        dList.push_back(sFighters(vec[i], vec[i-1]));
        std::erase(vec, vec[i]); std::erase(vec, vec[i-1]); // c++20 features
    }
    StartFightMode(); // for start fight player1 and player2
}

void FinishFight(int win, int lose)
{
    if (const auto& it = std::find_if(dList.begin(), dList.end(),
    [win,lose] (const auto& st)
    {return (st->GetID() == p1 || st->GetID() == p2); }
    ); it != dList.end())
    {
        dList.erase(it);
    }
    vec.push_back(win);

    if (dList.empty() && vec_size > 1)
    {
        MakeList();
        return;
    }

    if (dList.empty() && vec.size() == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Winner player id: " << vec.begin() << std::endl; 
        return;
    }

    
    StartFightMode(); // check dList and start fight player1 and player2
}
```

Comment: Well, what did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger? Any unexpected variable changes or values?

Comment: yea when up next tour matching random ram numbers example (598440672 vs 598441312)

Comment: Fyi, `for (auto i = vec.size() - 1; i > 0; ` is a recipe for disaster if the `vec` is ever empty. In that case, `vec.size()` can  return an unsigned `size_type` zero, you then subtract `1`, which causes unsigned underflow, and before you know it you're off and running in a 2^32 - 1 iteration loop (if 32bit, worse on 64bit). In your case having an even number of slots in `vec` would eventually produce a similar catastrophe. I.e. 6-1=5 ..3..1..underflow. The only way that loop doesn't end in sorrow is if it guarantees an odd number of entries on inception.

Comment: Honestly, I'm sure that this code would be a lot simpler if you used an associative container such as `std::set` and `std::map` instead of `std::vector`.  IMO, doing this type of error-prone erasure logic is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

My c++ is a little rusty, but in MakeList if i is unsigned and you're subtracting two from it in each iteration of the loop it might never be less than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

in the loop `for (auto i = vec.size() - 1; i > 0;` `i` will be unsigned long long. So `vec.size()` is even `i` will be odd. When `i==1` and you call `i-=2` `i` will become `2^64-1>0` so the loop will continue.

Solution1: instead of `auto` write `int` as the type of `i` (you will have a small loss in speed but should be neglegable)

Solution2: Go from the beggining and iterate forwards.

Impertant note: `std::erase` will delete all elements which are equal to `vec[i]` or `vec[i-1]`. If you have an other element equal to one of them the size of `vec` will decrease by more than 2 so in the next loop you will index out from `vec`. Use `pop_back()` instead (much faster too)